# Call an Apex method from a render check

Tags: apex, visualforce, rendered

Is it possible to call an Apex method (not a getter) from a `render` check?  I have tried multiple ways but get errors such as "Unknown method: readOnlyField()". I've included a stripped down version of the code I'm working with.  I'm willing to use `outputPanels` around the output/input fields but they rely on `render` checks so I doubt that will help.

I would like to avoid using JS to lock down the fields afterwards due to other complications on the page.

Apex:

```
public Set<String> readOnlyFields = new Set<String>{'ReadOnlyField1'};
public Boolean readOnlyField(String checkString){
    return readOnlyFields.contains(checkString);
}
```

VF:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Dynamic List" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!dynamicFields}" var="f">
        <apex:inputField value="{!utilityDetails[f]}" rendered="{!IF(readOnlyField(f), false, true)}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!utilityDetails[f]}" rendered="{!IF(readOnlyField(f), true, false)}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't provide parameters to a function that way (`readOnlyField(f)`), so you would indeed need getters. The closest approximation would be a map:

```
public Map<String, Boolean> readOnlyField { get; set; }
// ... //
readOnlyField = new Map<String, Boolean> { 'Name' => false /* , ... */ };
```

Since missing keys will cause a crash, you'll have to make sure your map is fully populated.

Edit:

As an alternative, make a wrapper class, and use that instead:

```
public class Field {
    public String fieldName { get; set; }
    public Boolean readOnly { get; set; }
}
public Field[] fieldList { get; set; }
```

Then, you can render a list of Fields:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!fieldList}" var="field">
    <apex:inputField rendered="{!not field.readOnly}" value="{!record[field.fieldname]}" />
    <apex:outputField rendered="{!field.readOnly}" value="{!record[field.fieldName]}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I like this idea.  I'll try it out.  I'll populate the new map as I load up the field list to make sure it is fully populated, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce doesn't support passing method arguments to methods from VF expressions.

In this case, you will have to create a wrapper class with field name, and mutability and use those values in the expressions.

Apex Wrapper Class:

```
public class FieldInfo {
    public String fieldName {get;set;}
    public Boolean readOnly {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public Set<FieldInfo> dynamicFields {get;set;} //construct dynamic fields with readonly visibility
```

VF:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Dynamic List" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!dynamicFields}" var="f">
        <apex:inputField value="{!utilityDetails[f.fieldName]}" rendered="{!Not(f.readOnly)}" />
        <apex:outputField value="{!utilityDetails[f.fieldName]}" rendered="{!f.readOnly}" />
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```